# Vertically center 2 floating divs

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. I want to achieve something like this:
[image]

I have a div with fixed height, and 2 other divs inside, with variable / unknown height, which I want to have

a) vertically centered
b) floating left /right

Right now I am trying something like this.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">This is left</div>
    <div class="right">This should be right</div>
 </div>
```

```
.wrapper:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.left {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.right {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Everything is perfectly centered, but the right div is next to the left one, and not on the right side. As soon as I start to put in

```
float: right;
```

into my right class, it is on the right side, but not centered anymore. And I have no clue how to achieve this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The CSS you posted doesn't generate the result in your image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a really cleaver answer to this at http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/  It suggests this code:

```
.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

There are other solutions to this problem also, but this is the most simple.  You can then just float each box left or right.

EDIT: another link with a lot of ways of doing this http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: Ohh great, that's really simple and works like charm. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using Flexbox, e.g.

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
}

.left {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: red;
}

.right {
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hafpuvtq/

More info: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I agree this works.  But you will also want to put height: 100% on the wrapper if you want the effect of both being horizontally aligned in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the html, body elements of **height: 100%** and **margin and padding of 0** outside the container class first before declaring any of the following classes:

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box1"></div>
        <div class="box2"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    height: 100px;
}

.box1 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}

.box2 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    float: right;
}
```

The left and right both have to contain floats; left box for **float: left;** and right box for **float: right;**

Answer (score 0):

That's right - floating an element removes it from the document flow, so it can't align itself to its parent element's `line-height`. Instead, put a wrapper `div` around each of the two child elements, and float the wrappers, left and right respectively. Make sure their `height` is `100%`, and then vertically align the children inside them, as you currently are.

See http://jsfiddle.net/conLs2fd/6/.

Comment: As @Michael Buckley suggests, there's a lot of different ways to do this. I recommended this approach since it follows the way you've done it in your sample, but you might find some of the other approaches suit you better (keep in mind the backward compatibility concerns of flexbox and css-transforms)

Answer (score 0):

this answer is just css

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

.left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: lightgray;
    display:inline-block;
}

.right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: gray;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left child">This is left</div>
    <div class="right child">This should be right</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it that involves using `text-align: justify` on the `.wrapper` parent block.  If you can specify the height of `.wrapper`, you 
can set `line-height` to the same value of the height.

Add a `:after` pseudo-element of `height: 0` to force a second line for the line box containing the elements, which will allow the justification to work.

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  height: 100px; /* for demo only */
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: justify;
}
.wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.left, .right {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
.left {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.right {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">This is left</div>
  <div class="right">This should be right</div>
</div>
```